# Numpy logically merging boolean arrays with numpy.NaN

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have 2 numpy arrays. The **first** one will **always** contain **ONLY** True or False values. The **second** may contain **True** or **False**, or it could have **numpy.NaN**. I want to merge the 2 arrays such that if the second array doesn't have a True or False value (it's value is numpy.NaN), it will take the value from the same location as the first array, otherwise, it will take on the True or False value. Confusing? Great! Here are some examples:

```
# example 1
a1 = np.array([True, False, True, False, True], dtype=object)
a2 = np.array([np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN], dtype=object)
output = a1.combinaficate(a2)
# prints [True, False, True, False, True]

# example 2
a1 = np.array([True, False, True, False, True], dtype=object)
a2 = np.array([np.NaN, True, np.NaN, False, np.NaN], dtype=object)
output = a1.combinaficate(a2)
# prints [True, True, True, False, True]

# example 3
a1 = np.array([True, True, True, True, True], dtype=object)
a2 = np.array([np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, False, np.NaN], dtype=object)
output = a1.combinaficate(a2)
# prints [True, True, True, False, True]

# example 4
a1 = np.array([False, False, False, False, False], dtype=object)
a2 = np.array([np.NaN, np.NaN, True, False, np.NaN], dtype=object)
output = a1.combinaficate(a2)
# prints [False, False, True, False, False]
```

I know that I could write a for loop, but the spirit of the question is "Is there a way to use strictly numpy to make this computation?".

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? The casting is necessary because `np.isnan` doesn't like booleans. You could also use `pd.isnull` and not do the casting if you are willing to use pandas.

```
output = a2.copy()
idx = np.isnan(a2.astype(np.float16))
output[idx] = a1[idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
a2 = np.where(a2 != a2, a1, a2)
print(a2)
```

---

e.g.:

```py
a1 = np.array([False, False, False, False, False], dtype=object)
a2 = np.array([np.NaN, np.NaN, True, False, np.NaN], dtype=object)

a2 = np.where(a2 != a2, a1, a2)
print(a2)
```

Prints:

```
[False False True False False]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize as follows:

```
 def serial_combinaficate(a1, a2):
     if isinstance(a2, bool):
        return a2
     else:
        return a1

 combinaficate = np.vectorize(serial_combinaficate)  

 # example 4
 a1 = np.array([False, False, False, False, False], dtype=object)
 a2 = np.array([np.NaN, np.NaN, True, False, np.NaN], dtype=object)
 output = combinaficate(a1, a2)
 print(output)
 # prints [False, False, True, False, False]
```

Comment: what is wrong with this? It works

Comment: IDK who down voted, but I'm not objectively mad at it. I'm not excited to pump a function into a method, but its not terrible. There is probably some dispute amongst what would "Is there a way to use strictly numpy to make this computation?" actually mean.

Comment: @Shmack: `numpy.vectorize` is basically just a `for` loop under the hood. It gives a function a NumPy ufunc interface without actually doing the work at NumPy level or NumPy speed internally. (It's also got subtle issues with output dtype and function reevaluation that people keep missing, though they don't end up mattering here.)

Comment: I see. Thank you for shedding light on that for me.